# Asus Rampage III and Corsair DRAM Settings

Tags: bios, dram

Recently I flashed the BIOS (from 1301 to 1502) of my Asus Rampage III Extreme.  But I lost the settings and now only 16GB out of 24GB of DRAM in the system is recognized.  Does anyone has the correct DRAM setting for:

- 2 kits of cmz12gx3m3a1600c9 (Corsair Vengenance 12GB kit) on Asus Rampage III Extreme?

Current I have 9-9-9-24 1N at 1.5v, but only 16GB is showing.  I even tried to up the voltage to 1.65v, still no joy.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is only 16GB showing? In the BIOS? In the OS? (And if in the OS, what OS? Be as specific as possible, like "Windows 7 Professional, SP1, 64-bit".)

Comment: Both in BIOS and Win 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS, change the "Memory Configuration Protect" setting to "Enabled".

Comment: Already have that enabled, anything else that you can think of?